# Cocos2d v 0.99 - does it work on OS3?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Is the latest version of Cocos2D compatible with iOS3?
When I change `#define CC_ENABLE_PROFILERS 1` in `ccConfig`, I'm able to compile the file in iOS4. However, trying to run the file in iOS3 is giving me an error in iOS3 (I tried `#define CC_COMPATIBILITY_WITH_0_8 1`) as well.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run iOS4 compiled code on iOS3 device? Maybe you just have to change the SDK in XCode?